# Classic ASP in 64bit mode and .NET COM DLL register problem

Tags: .net, com, asp-classic, 64-bit

I'm running Classic ASP on Windows 2008 Server x64 in 64bit mode.
ADODB is running fine in 64bit with classic ASP. I have a problem with mine .NET COM DLL.
I have created a .NET COM DLL with such code as an sample:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace TestNamespace
{
    [Guid("C446E97E-B415-4677-B99E-9644657FC98"),
    ProgId("TestNamespace.TestClass"),
    ComVisible(true)]
    public class TestClass
    {
        [ComVisible(true)]
        public void TestMethod(string s)
        {
            //some code that uses System.Messaging to send a message
        }
    }
}
```

The DLL is compiled for Any CPU. In ASP I create object and execute method:

```
Set test = Server.CreateObject("TestNamespace.TestClass")
test.TestMethod("test string")
Set test = Nothing
```

I'm registering DLL using RegAsm:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\RegAsm.exe /tlb /codebase TestNamespace.dll
```

On x86 platform the ASP and the DLL are running fine.

On Windows 2008 Server I've tried:

- Compile DLL for x64 and register using ...\Framework64 \v2.0.50727\RegAsm.exe
- Compile for different platforms and placing in different locations including GAC
- many more

The errors (different situations):

- Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01ad' Server.CreateObject Failed
- Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 80070002' Server.CreateObject Failed
- Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 800401f3' Server.CreateObject Failed
- Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 80131040' Server.CreateObject Failed

The only way it worked on Windows 2008 Server x64, when ASP app pool was switched to 32bit mode. But I need it to work in 64bit!
I think the problem is not with permissions, because 32bit have worked.

Anyone have experience in classic ASP and .NET COM both running in 64bit?

Comment: Found, that everything is ok until System.Messaging is used in the method. A windows service, that consume messages, created and installed for x64 platform is working fine with System.Messaging.
Probably it is a problem with 64bit asp.dll process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found, that everything is ok until System.Messaging is used in the method. A windows service, that consume messages, created and installed for x64 platform is working fine with System.Messaging. Probably it is a problem with 64bit asp.dll process.

Answer (score 1):

"But I need it to work in 64bit!" Why? You will not ever be able to load any 32 bit DLLS into a 64 bit process [and you will need to go out of proc if you need to do such communication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973190.aspx#64mig_topic5) - is that what you want? What do you plan to do with your extra address space?

[A topical blog post regarding what you're trying to go 64 bit for is this one by Rick Byers](http://blogs.msdn.com/rmbyers/archive/2009/06/08/anycpu-exes-are-usually-more-trouble-then-they-re-worth.aspx)

If you really do believe this to be a good investment of your time, [there's an article here on the internals of 64 bit COM which might help in figuring it out for yourself from first principles.](https://windowshpc.net/Resources/Documents/64-bit%20Insider%20Volume%201%20Issue%2012.pdf)

(I harbour similar instincts to go 64 bit ASAP and be done with all that legacy <64 bittedness, but sometimes things arent broke.)